# How do I create a User Edited UITableView?

Tags: uitableview, customization, tableview

So I made an app designed around navigating through tons of information for a school. A large portion of the app is huge table views of 100+ people for the faculty roster that redirects you to that person's specific information. What we have found is that the people who use it navigate to the same people every time, and find it annoying to scroll through a huge list of names to find the one they want. I want to solve this problem by giving the users a 'favorites page' where they can add the faculty they frequently use to their own table view. Does anyone know how I could do such a thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for removing a cell u can use the following code

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

to get favorite page u have to create array and assign the cell which i s selected and pass the elements to favorites page...U can try the following link where u can search for passing the value between views..

http://www.youtube.com/user/GeekyLemon